# HPUX throwing an RST 30 seconds after a sucessful NFS mount

Tags: linux, nfs, hp-ux

We have an application written in Dot NET that basically allows Linux and Unix files to access symbolic links stored in the NFS "share". Customer was having issues with the NFS share becoming unavailable, and eventually having to reboot the windows system. We went out and bought a HPUX system with the same version of HPUX installed, got it running. Did some mounts to the NFS "SHARE" and discovered via wireshark, that HPUX is throwing an RST after 30 seconds, thus borking the connection. Solaris, Redhat, Centos, AIX dont do this. If necessary I can upload the wireshark trace. Any idea why HPUX would do that?

HP-UX HPUX1 B.11.31 U 
NFS3
TCPIP 4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not specified how you bought the HP-UX system, but considering their unpopular status right now and you not having on and buying a HP-UX server this time, I am under the impression, you've got from ebay or alike. In which case it did not come with any software support agreement, which you will most likely need.

There is a software product called ONCplus, (open network computing) whic is most probably installed with an earlier version on your machine. run the command

```
swlist -l bundle | grep -i onc
```

and note the version number. if it is less than `ONCplus B.11.31.19.1` there might lie your problem and you may need top upgrade this bundle, which in turn will need an HP software support contract

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, we did just purchase it from an online refurbishing house for the purpose of supporting a customer who is experiencing this same issue with NFS.....swlist -l bundle | grep -i onc
ONCplus               B.11.31.09.01  ONC+ 2.3

Comment: customer is at 11.31.08

Comment: strongly suggest you find a support agreement and upgrade to version 11.31.19.1 since both your customer's  and your systems are suffering from this problem

Comment: Customer decided to move away from HPUX to redhat, so this is no longer an issue. For today. Thanks Mel for you help.